# Making multiple predictions with a CNN in order to train a global loss function

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I have a CNN written in pytorch that outputs audio and I've been looking to improve audio quality by adding a comparison of RFFTs between the predicted and actual values. The current network outputs 128 samples per prediction, which is too small for a meaningful RFFT. I recently experimented with enlarging the prediction to 1024 samples, but this significantly slows down the training process.

I was wondering if it's possible to design a loss function that evaluates an FFT for an audio buffer that's 1024 samples long containing 8 contiguous predictions of 128 samples? In this case, the sample-based loss would still exist for the 128-sample predictions, but an extra RFFT-based loss would kick in once a batch of 1024 was ready. I've never attempted this sort of thing so I don't know if it's possible. Thanks in advance for any tips!